# I can't find Bluetooth devices

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I don't understand why, but my laptop isn't discovering Bluetooth devices. When I go to the "Add Bluetooth or other device" option and try to connect my Bluetooth headset, no devices are displayed. Despite all my efforts, such as uninstalling and restarting for the automatic reinstallation of drivers by Windows, attempts to update drivers, and even experimenting with older driver versions, the issue persists.

It's worth noting that the laptop, originally owned by a relative and of Spanish origin, is relatively old. When I first received it, I noticed that Bluetooth couldn't find devices, and although I tried to solve the problem at that time, I wasn't successful. Interestingly, last night, when I tried turning on Bluetooth without much expectation, I managed to connect my headset. However, when I tried again this morning, I couldn't replicate the previous success as no devices were found.

I've checked if the laptop is in airplane mode, confirmed that Bluetooth is enabled in the settings, and ran the specific Bluetooth troubleshooter, all without success. Given this situation, I'd like to know if there's any solution or additional guidance that can be provided to resolve this persistent issue.

Comment: Sounds like you don’t have BT card installed, is there any evidence, you do have a BT card?

Comment: @Ramhound, OP states headphones connected at least once.

Comment: On Windows, I've found Bluetooth connectivity short-lived and prone to issues. You might try using another OS, such as running Linux from a bootable USB (no need to install on the PC! E.G. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview). Another possibility is to try a USB Bluetooth adapter (e.g., https://www.amazon.com/s?k=bluetooth+adapter); some are $US10. Perhaps it might work better than the internal one.

Comment: A suggestion to use Linux instead of Windows is ridiculous if the author is only familiar with Windows.  I have more than 5 Windows 10 and Windows 11 devices and every single one has flawless BT. The author can’t be switching to Linux just to use a BT headset

Comment: @John where can I install the manufacturer's hardware diagnostic app to identify potential issues with my laptop? Additionally, I'm uncertain about what a Bluetooth card is. Is it a physical component, or is it an application that I can install?

Comment: Bluetooth is physical hardware that needs drivers and a software stack to work. It can be a standalone chipset or, morel likely, part of the WiFi card. As suggested, the first thing you should check is Device Manager where it should appear under its own category. If not then you have a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding; it's truly a great help. My Bluetooth appears in the Device Manager, indicating that I have it, but it still isn't working. Do you have any further suggestions on something else I can try?

Comment: Now you should perhaps try to remove the previous pairing (headphones) and try to pair again. This is needed in many situations when the output device has been used with another devices (e.g. a phone). Many time it just manually reconnects with the desktop PC but more often than not re-pairing is needed. Nothing exclusive to Windows, it happens a lot with Desktop Linux and MacOS as well.

Comment: Thanks again for responding. The issue is a bit different. The only time I managed to connect my headphones to my Windows, I did it. They were paired, but when I disconnected and tried to reconnect, that's where the problem arises. My laptop doesn't show any devices at all, neither my headset nor any others.